# I want to auto-populate a row of cells when a condition is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Project Tracker by date and condition formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFvFe.png)

The problem has a column of dates that need compared to a row (headers) of dates to find the column the comparing date "belongs to."

|  | 8/8/2022 | 8/15/2022 | 8/22/2022 | 8/29/2022 | 9/5/2022 | 9/12/2022 | 9/19/2022 | 9/26/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/9/2022 |  |  |  |  | FEA Dev |  |  |  |

As is shown, the date "9/9/2022" belong to the column headed by "9/5/2022". The idea is that the headers define weeks and the entry needs put into the right week.

The formula tried is `=IF(AND($A4>=C$3,$A4<D$3),:FEA Dev","")`. Currently it is being placed in each cell under the headers so SPILL is not helpful.

The headers will "shift" in some unspecified manner.

The hope is for a way to get SPILL to work.

Comment: Please post your question as text, you can link to a screencap or two is ok, but it should support your text, not replace it. Also, can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to to include actual text. It is useful to use proper text because people can copy out things like the formulae without having to manually rewrite it themselves. You can include images to help clarify but they should not be the only content of your question. [su] includes the [ability to create tables amongst the formatting tools](https://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) so that your table can be recreated by others.

Answer (score 0):

The precise problem for why `SPILL` won't work for your formula is that, like a number of functions, `AND` (and `OR`) only provide one single output. So the formula ends up with a single result, not multiple results, and there is nothing to spill.

If you rewrite the formula to accomplish the goal but not use `AND`, you will get `SPILL` results.

For example:

```
=IF(A4 < B3:H3, "", IF(A4<C3:I3,"FFA Dev",""))
```

will spill across each row and if you'd like a single formula that spills across the rows and down the column, you can use:

```
=IF(A4:A5<B3:H3,"",IF(A4:A5<C3:I3,"FFA Dev",""))
```

(In both, you'd modify addresses as required.)

Notice that use of `SPILL` allows you to drop the `$` in the cell addresses.

This leaves the problem of addressing the final column. If a date like Sep 27 is to appear in a column headed Sep 26, then you need to find a different formula, or add a "dummy" column (dummy in that it has the header of Oct 3 in this case, but there are NEVER meant to be row entries in the column... it just exists for the header to be useful to the formula) with the next week's date for the header.

The part about the dates shifting left or right is pretty open. If by that you mean the labels might **change** rather than physically move, then the formula will work just fine. If they "get up and move" as in drag and drop perhaps, that's a whole new ball of wax. Excel will not handle the address changes nicely. However, in between the two extremes, there's copy, say, the right four dates and move them to the starting column (column B here) and adding more to their right, that's fine. Putting a starting date in the first header and a formula to add seven into each header to its right, that's fine.

And if none of the headers are "real dates?" In a formal Excel Table for example. In that case, you'd need to add a mechanism for converting each into a date as it is used in the formula. So the real headers stay text, but they are used as dates in the formula. Just more complicated is all, but keeping it working with `SPILL` might give you less options than you like.

But the absolute basic problem with your formula is that `AND` (and others) will not give multiple results for Excel to work with. Interestingly, even formulas whose descriptions always said if multiple results are returned only the first one ("top, left") would be passed as the result, for display and as feed into other formulas, actually do produce, internally, their full array of results and with the right coercion can be made to pass them on to the rest of the formula. But `AND` doesn't look like it does even that. So, until someone cracks that nut, you just can't use it for `SPILL` formulas to be spilling anything.

(If you'd like to try, the idea is that such a function not be the "outside" function in a formula. You use a compliant function outside of it to pull the internal array it produces past it, so to speak, and then the full array is available to the calculation from then outward. It's just that `AND` seems resistant to this.)